# Need Help implementing Perforce depot or GitHub repot that allows offsite cloud hosting with onsite primary server syncing between local machines

Tags: unity-game-engine, github, cloud, perforce, unreal-engine4

Essentially, I have been working towards finding a simple solution using either perforce or GitHub desktop or a combination of the two.

I would like to create a repot/depot on a GitHub server or another hosting service which will store unity and unreal projects among other files and folders.

I then need to clone it to a local server.

Finally i have three local machines that I want to have local versions of the projects that can pull, push and sync to the local server

which will finally push back up to the hosted repot/depot for others to grab and do the same.

I'm trying to work with a system that doesn't require always on connection to the internet for working locally with a team, but can be hosted globally so I don't have to maintain a server for global connection

Is this possible?.

Comment: This isn't a StackOverflow question per se as it's node code related.  You'd probably be better served on GameDev or some other StackExchange site.  That said, I'll still answer.

Comment: @Immersive note that the help page describes "what topics can I ask about here" as explicitly including "software tools commonly used by programmers," and [this meta thread recommends asking questions about version control tools like GitHub here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157888/what-site-is-good-for-github-questions). To my eye, this doesn't look out of line with [other eg. GitHub-related questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github).

Comment: @DMGregory Ahh, cool.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Git does what you're asking for inherently.  You don't *need* to push/pull against a remote server, you can simply push/pull against your peers (either through a locally-hosted git server, or just networked file shares).  You will need to setup your git client for all the various endpoints.  If you're determined to stick with the star-network model (single 'authority' server) than it does make keeping end points tidy.

Comment: Thanks I will post this question else ware.

Comment: I posted on gamedev and I was told me to ask a programming exchange... What other stack exchange might be more suited for this question?

Comment: You asked this on GameDev and were provided with a link to [a meta thread recommending several sites to ask on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157888/299045), including here, SuperUser, or ServerFault.

Comment: Thanks Gregory, im kind of new to this so im trying my best to ask in the appropriate forums

Comment: So then immersive or Gregory to clarify. I can have a git repo on the server that serves as the main source of truth for that location? i can then have that repo pushed and pulled against local workstations? do i need to mirror or clone the repo to the local workstations or is there another method im not getting? Finally are you then saying i can take that server repo and have it linked to GitHub to sync changes to other Offices/Locations/Sites inherently in git?

Comment: You may find this interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820730/how-to-best-set-up-a-central-git-repository-from-a-current-existing-local-git

Yes, use `git clone --bare` to clone from your cloud service to local server, then a standard `git clone` from your local server to your clients/workstations.  Workstations will push/pull against local server, and local server can push/pull from cloud service.